# Why does there appear to be a different number of unique colors available on the Mac as compared to Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, text, antialiasing, screen-capture

A screen capture of a text like "Mac display uses more colors" which apparently on windows shows just 2 colors ( Black and White ), shows nearly 240 unique colors on Mac. Both images have been saved as BMPs.

Can anyone please explain why there is such a huge difference and how to capture or read in such a way that I get just 2 colors instead of 240 different colors (different shades of grey, black)?

Comment: Note that even with ClearType turned on, the anti-aliasing algorithms on Mac OS X are *very* different compared to those used in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's antialiasing, and Windows does it too, if ClearType is turned on.

Comment: Thanks for Quick response..Could you please tell me how to turn off on Mac? My requirement is that I wont be using "clear type" on windows and so would not want the anti-aliasing alogirthms either on Windows or Mac.

Comment: @Ashok: Where and how to turn off anti-aliasing on a Mac is a question for the Mac user group, [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. I have posted it on apple forum.

Comment: @Ashok: **Please** don't require your users to turn anti-aliasing off just to be able to use your application.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the much greater range of colours is due to sub-pixel antialiasing being used on the Mac, and presumably turned off (or otherwise not showing in the screendump) on Windows.

SPAA takes advantage of knowledge that each pixel on an LCD is actually three sub-pixels which are controlled independently. So even though a whole pixel width might be coloured in the screen capture, when displayed only a third (or perhaps two-thirds) of the pixel is lit.

Much more info is available on wikipedia, as per usual!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering

Comment: If it's just 240 different shades of grey, per the question, that's 8-bit full-pixel antialiasing.  Sub-pixel antialiasing would be nearer 800 colors I think, and there definitely would be different hues present.